# Avoiding multiple try catches when every line can throw

Tags: java, exception, syntax

Suppose I have the following statements:

```
        try {
            this.startTime = dateFormat.parse(startTime);
            this.endTime =  dateFormat.parse(endTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here both lines can throw an exception, but if startTime is empty but endTime isn't, at the end of this block both will be null.

Is there a way to catch exceptions and still go through each statement without making a try catch block for each of statement?

Comment: wrap `dateFormat.parse(xxx);` with your own method and just do try/catch inside.

Comment: You could assign `endTime` in a `finally` block, which itself would have a try catch.  But this is uglier than what you already have.

Comment: @Maciej yeah but if I had more different statements then it wouldn't generalize. Oh well.

Comment: @shinzou Normally not every statement throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The execution of in the `try`-block will be "broken" after an exception is thrown. So if you want subsequent lines to be executed *despite* an exception is thrown, they should not be in the `try` block. So you will probably end up with:

```
try {
    this.startTime = dateFormat.parse(startTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    this.endTime =  dateFormat.parse(endTime);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Extract a method like `parseDate` to make things better:

```
    this.startTime = parseDate(startTime);
    this.endTime = parseDate(endTime);
```